# JS loop that runs forwards, reaches the end then runs backwards and forwards indefinitely

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a bit of JS that changes the value of an HTML attribute, it uses setInterval and goes from 0-150, reaches 150 and starts again back to 0.

I am trying to work out if its possible to reach the end then run backwards, like:

-150 ==> 0 ==> 150 ==> 0 ==> -150 ==> 0 etc

This is the code I am using at the moment:

```js
var liquifyVal = -150
window.setInterval(function() {
  liquifyVal = (liquifyVal + 1) % 150;
  document.getElementById('liquid').setAttribute('scale', liquifyVal);
}, 25);
```

```css
h1 {
  filter: url("#liquify");
  font-size: 100px;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  Hello
</h1>
<svg id="svgeffects">
   <defs>
  <filter class="safari_only" id="liquify">
   <feTurbulence baseFrequency="0.015" numOctaves="2" result="warp" type="fractalNoise"></feTurbulence>
   <feDisplacementMap id="liquid" in="SourceGraphic" in2="warp" scale="150" xChannelSelector="R" yChannelSelector="B"></feDisplacementMap>
  </filter>
   </defs>
 </svg>
```

Fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/8efk2a1q/ (think this only works in Chrome for now)

Design explanation-wise its so there isn't a jarring end to the animation, instead there is a seamless back and forwards.

Any help would be great!

Thanks.

Comment: Looks to also work in FF 56 as well as Opera.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could declare an `increment` variable outside of the loop, and assign it `1` or `-1` when the peak/trough is reached. It would also be nicer to only select the element in question *once*, rather than over and over again each time the interval runs:

```js
const liquid = document.getElementById('liquid');
let liquifyVal = -150;
let increment = 1;
setInterval(() => {
  liquifyVal += increment;
  if (liquifyVal === 150) increment = -1;
  else if (liquifyVal === -150) increment = 1;
  liquid.setAttribute('scale', liquifyVal);
}, 25);
```

```css
h1 {
  filter: url("#liquify");
  font-size: 100px;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  Hello
</h1>
<svg id="svgeffects">
  <defs>
    <filter class="safari_only" id="liquify">
      <feTurbulence baseFrequency="0.015" numOctaves="2" result="warp" type="fractalNoise"></feTurbulence>
      <feDisplacementMap id="liquid" in="SourceGraphic" in2="warp" scale="150" xChannelSelector="R" yChannelSelector="B"></feDisplacementMap>
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thats awesome, thanks! Very clever :) yes I agree with the last thing you said, was also struggling to visualise the most efficient concept as well as the answer. Thanks again!